# Is there any difference between past participles and past participle adjectives

Tags: adjectives, participles

My grammar book says

1. We can also use **much** or **very much** before **a past participle** which is part of a passive.

Ex) The new by-pass was (very) much needed.

2. We don't use **much** but can use **very much** before **past participle adjectives**

Ex) I was very much surprised by her news. (or I was surprised ...; but not I was much surprised ...)

I'm confused. What's the difference between them? I thought both are the same thing.

Comment: I simply do not agree with your text.

Comment: You're right. "I was very much surprised by her news" is a better sentence than your book is a grammar resource.

Comment: I think it's time for you to get a different book. There are no differences between the two.